# Error in starting Keycloak dev environment server

Tags: java, jdbc, keycloak

I've already set the path variables but still getting this error.
Keycloak-21.0.2

```
C:\Program Files\keycloak-21.0.2\bin>kc.bat start-dev
2023-04-13 21:58:58,216 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: <request>, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: false
2023-04-13 21:59:01,941 WARN  [io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources] (main) Datasource <default> enables XA but transaction recovery is not enabled. Please enable transaction recovery by setting quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true, otherwise data may be lost if the application is terminated abruptly
2023-04-13 21:59:06,112 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
2023-04-13 21:59:06,241 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
2023-04-13 21:59:06,264 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
2023-04-13 21:59:07,756 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread: keycloak-default) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.sql.SQLException: Acquisition timeout while waiting for new connection
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool.handlerFromSharedCache(ConnectionPool.java:321)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:249)
        at io.agroal.pool.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:86)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.customized.QuarkusConnectionProvider.getConnection(QuarkusConnectionProvider.java:23)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.<init>(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:272)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.recording.PrevalidatedQuarkusMetadata.buildSessionFactoryOptionsBuilder(PrevalidatedQuarkusMetadata.java:68)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:72)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:72)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$LazyPersistenceUnit.get(JPAConfig.java:165)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$1.run(JPAConfig.java:66)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool.handlerFromSharedCache(ConnectionPool.java:298)
        ... 23 more

2023-04-13 21:59:14,212 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
2023-04-13 21:59:14,212 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to obtain JDBC connection
2023-04-13 21:59:14,214 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Acquisition timeout while waiting for new connection
2023-04-13 21:59:14,214 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
```

I was trying to open the dev server of Keycloak but in trun keep getting this instead.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there is no database server running at the specified URL.

> By default, the server uses the dev-file database. This is the default database that the server will use to persist data and only exists for development use-cases.

Check [this](https://www.keycloak.org/server/db) guide for configuring a database for Keycloak and make sure if you are connecting to a remote database Keycloak has access to the remote system.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same error and it seems Keycloak cannot get the default number of connections of 5 to set up the pool and in my mysql DB not sure what was the issue but managed to get Keycloak up and running by setting the following three values as 1:

KC_DB_POOL_INITIAL_SIZE, KC_DB_POOL_MIN_SIZE and KC_DB_POOL_MAX_SIZE